# simple Circle on circle Collision libgdx

Tags: java, android, c++, libgdx, geometry

made two circles one of radius 8(image 16x16)
and one of radius 20( image 40x40)
i am calling the circle over overlap method and the collsion is just off.  It is colliding with  a circle that is around the 0,0 point of where ever my image of the ball is.  the bullet can go within the ball on the bottom and right sides.

```
    public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture ballImage, bulletImage;
OrthographicCamera cam;
Circle ball;
Array <Circle> bullets;
long lastShot;

@Override
public void create ()
{
    System.out.println("game created");
    ballImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.png"));
    bulletImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bullet.png"));

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true,320,480);//true starts top right false starts top left

    batch = new SpriteBatch();  

    ball = new Circle();
    ball.radius=20;
    ball.x=320/2-ball.radius; // half screen size - half image
    ball.y=480/2-ball.radius;


    bullets = new Array<Circle>();
     spawnBullet();

/* 


    batch.draw(bulletImage,bullet.x,bullet.y);
    bullet.x++;
    bullet.y++; */

}

public void spawnBullet()
{
    Circle bullet = new Circle();
    bullet.radius=8;
    bullet.x=0;
    bullet.y=0;

    bullets.add(bullet);
    lastShot = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void render ()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(ballImage,ball.x,ball.y);

    for(Circle bullet: bullets)
    {
        batch.draw(bulletImage, bullet.x, bullet.y);
    }

    batch.end();



    if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {           
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3();
        pos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),0);
        cam.unproject(pos);

        ball.y = pos.y - ball.radius;   
        ball.x = pos.x - ball.radius ;
    }

    //if(TimeUtils.nanoTime()-lastShot >1000000000) one second
        //spawnBullet();

    Iterator<Circle> i = bullets.iterator();    
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        Circle bullet = i.next();
        bullet.x++;
        bullet.y++;
        if(bullet.overlaps(ball))
        {
            System.out.println("overlap");
            i.remove();

            }

    }

}   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your bullet and the ball are 2 circles, like you said you don't need an overlap method.
It is simple: 2 circles collide, if their distance is smaller then the sum of their radiuses.

To calculate the distance you need to make a squareroot. This is a pretty expensive calculation, so it would be better to use squared distance and squared sum of radiuses:

```
float xD = ball.x - bullet.x;      // delta x
float yD = ball.y - bullet.y;      // delta y
float sqDist = xD * xD + yD * yD;  // square distance
boolean collision = sqDist <= (ball.radius+bullet.radius) * (ball.radius+bullet.radius);
```

Thats it.

Also in your `cam.setToOrtho` you wrote a cooment:

> //true starts top right false starts top left

Thats wrong, it is top left or bottom left. By default it is bottom left, because this is the way a coordinate system works normaly. The top left is, because the monitor addresses pixels starting from top left = pixel 1.

**EDIT:** this should be the problem: The coordinates you give the `batch.draw` method are the left lower corner of the `Texture` by default, if you are using the "y = Down"-System it should be the top left corner (you have to try i am not sure).
The `Circle`s position instead is its center.
To solve the problem you need to adjust the position like this (for "y = Up"-System):

```
batch.draw(bulletImage, bullet.x - bullet.radius, bullet.y - bullet.radius);
```

It is possible, that the same formula works also for the "y = Down"-System but i am not sure

Comment: it is still doing the same thing, the overlap function is fine. worked just like yours.  i think it is just believing the center of my ball is at the top left corner(0,0) of the ball image rather then the center.

Comment: the position of a `Texture` is the lower left corner by default. If you change the coordinate system it should be the top left corner.
I am not sure, if the same counts for the `Circle` class.

Comment: now its just doing the same thing in reverse, but do you understand what im saying about the coordinates though? and the collision its detecting rather then what i want.  I can post a picture if need be. just this problem has taken way to long.